# onClick event on table row's href

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, contextmenu

I created a table with DataTables and the documents in each row are href'd and populated by local JSON data.

I have a context menu and one of the options is to "Open a Document", which would be the same as clicking on an href and opening the document that way.

I'm trying to grab the attribute (or right thing) that would be triggered by an onClick event. Since the table data is integrated into DataTables, however, I'm not sure how I would proceed. Any thoughts?

#### Rendering DataTable:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        // { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Titles" }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path", 
          ordering:  true, targets: [2],
          render: function(data, type, row) { // ---- wraps docs in anchors
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: [2]
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [0], visible: false },
      ],
      data: tableRes,
      language: { searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents" },
      lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500 ],
      order: [],
      pageLength: 500,
      paging: true,
      pagingType: "full_numbers"
    });
```

#### Attempting to open doc via context menu onClick:

```
$("li[data-action='open']").click(function(evt) {
      $(this).attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
    });
```

#### HTML context menu:

```
<ul class="custom-menu">
    <li data-action="open">Open Document</li>
    <li data-action="add" id="add-id">Set As Favorite</li>
    <li data-action="email">Email Document</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update: I found a (working) solution.

Basically the DataTable column of "Titles" has to be in the last position to properly correspond with each checkbox. I'm sure there's a solution where I can have columns come after and the checkbox appending will work, but this is okay for now.

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Titles" } // MUST be in last position to respond w/ checkboxes
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path", 
          ordering:  true, targets: [3],
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: [3]
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [1], visible: false },
      ],
```

...etc